# javascript promises, caching & angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have an angular service that takes care of loading items from the server and then when one items gets selected in a view, the corresponding item will be taken from the list of items and returned to the detail.

The problem I now have is when reloading the page, my items are not yet loaded, and thus my resolve fails, leading to a failure to reload.

```
  getItems = (): ng.IPromise<Array<any>> => {
        if (this.items != undefined) {
            return this.items;
        }

        return this.$http.get(url).then((result) => {
            this.items = result.data['items']; 
            return this.items;
        });
    }

    getItem= (id: any): ng.IPromise<any> => {

        return this.getItems().then(() => angular.forEach(this.items, (item: any) => {
            if (item.id === id) {
                return item;
            }
        }));
    }
```

I thought this piece of code (getItem) would return me a single item, but it returns again the entire collection.  How could i fix my code to get me to return the single item?

Comment: Where you are calling `getItem` function?

Comment: getItem is called from a resolve in my route

Comment: Calling `return` in a lambda handed to `forEach` has no use, especially it does not cause the external function to return. A `for ... of` loop is your best option here.

Answer (score 1):

if you can use es6-shim:

```
getItem= (id: any): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    return this.getItems().then(() => this.items.find( (item: any) => {
        return item.id === id;
    }));
}
```

Or you can use

```
getItem= (id: any): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    return this.getItems().then(() => this.items.filter( (item: any) => {
        return item.id === id;
    })[0]);
}
```